# Update Panel posts back after a period of inactivity

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have a asp.net user control in a SharePoint solution. This user control uses Telerik Asp.net Ajax controls to provide a basic datagrid CRUD operations. I use this grid in a web part on a page in SharePoint 2013.

I have a datagrid which is wrapped with RadAjaxPanel to ajaxify it.

It all works fine. However, let's say, I click the add new record button and it opens a form to fill, if I leave that form intact for a minute, then start to fill and submit, it does postback and cancels form.

However, if I  click on add new record and fill the form and submit, it all works fine. I guess there is a timeout somewhere which causes this, my two days of research did not help me to find it.

I was just wondering whether you have ever come across with this issue. I guess it does not matter whether it is Asp.net update panel or RadAjaxUpdatePanel, even if you have seen this issue on Asp.net update panel, that will help too.

I did not know what part of the code I should share, please let me know if you need any code to understand this issue.

There must be something on SharePoint script manager, and ajax manager, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Can admins transfer this question to sharepoint.stackoverflow.com please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a known bug in SharePoint 2013. People suggested to install December 2014 CU to solve it, but it did not solve it. Someone mentioned in this  [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c33d4a46-87d6-4dbc-a24c-cb8e5f9eb1ea/page-refresh-after-postback-from-updatepanel-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment) to make request to server via javascript event given interval. As my page does postback if I leave it about 20-30 sec idle, I call a random SP web service evet 15 sec which seems to resolve my issue. Please see below link which helped me to workaround this.